# finding average in pandas based on starttime and endtime

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to find average hours per location based on data from 2 data frames:

evc_locations.csv

```
location_id,charger_id,electricity_procurement_cost_per_kwh,electricity_dispensing_cost_per_kwh,zip_cd,state 
loc1001,charge11001,3,4.2,60611,illinois 
loc1001,charge11002,3,4.2,60611,illinois 
oc1001,charge11003,3,4.2,60611,illinois 
loc1002,charge11004,3,3.4,60611,illinois 
loc1002,charge11005,3,3.4,60611,illinois 
loc1003,charge11006,3,4.1,60611,illinois 
loc1004,charge11007,3,4.3,60612,illinois 
loc1004,charge11008,3,4.3,60612,illinois 
loc1005,charge11009,3,3.6,60612,illinois 
loc1005,charge11010,3,3.6,60612,illinois 
loc1005,charge11011,3,3.6,60612,illinois 
loc1006,charge11012,4,4.1,60613,florida 
loc1006,charge11013,4,4.1,60613,florida 
loc1006,charge11014,4,4.1,60613,florida 
loc1006,charge11015,4,4.1,60613,florida 
loc1007,charge11016,4,4.6,60613,florida 
loc1008,charge11017,4,4.25,60614,florida 
loc1008,charge11018,4,4.25,60614,florida 
loc1009,charge11019,4,4.33,60614,florida 
loc1010,charge11020,3,3.2,60615,california 
loc1010,charge11021,4,4.33,60615,california 
loc1010,charge11022,4,4.33,60615,california 
loc1010,charge11023,4,4.33,60615,california 
loc1010,charge11024,4,4.33,60615,california 
loc1011,charge11025,4,4.55,60615,california 
loc1011,charge11026,4,4.55,60615,california 
loc1011,charge11027,4,4.55,60615,california
```

evc_logs.csv

```
charger_id,cust_id,start_capacity,end_capacity,start_time,end_time 
charge11010,cust202196,09,433,01/01/2020 06:32 AM,01/01/2020 07:42 AM 
charge11003,cust202262,02,402,01/01/2020 06:31 AM,01/01/2020 07:41 AM 
charge11032,cust202018,33,416,01/01/2020 06:30 AM,01/01/2020 07:41 AM 
charge11027,cust202096,07,437,01/01/2020 06:32 AM,01/01/2020 07:40 AM 
charge11026,cust202043,40,444,01/01/2020 06:30 AM,01/01/2020 07:43 AM 
charge11022,cust202447,00,405,01/01/2020 06:30 AM,01/01/2020 07:43 AM 
charge11023,cust202407,34,447,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:43 AM 
charge11006,cust202166,25,405,01/01/2020 06:32 AM,01/01/2020 07:41 AM 
charge11034,cust202381,48,431,01/01/2020 06:30 AM,01/01/2020 07:41 AM 
charge11011,cust202499,22,448,01/01/2020 06:32 AM,01/01/2020 07:42 AM 
charge11009,cust202057,03,403,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:40 AM 
charge11018,cust202211,00,403,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:42 AM 
charge11031,cust202419,36,418,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:40 AM 
charge11002,cust202075,06,404,01/01/2020 06:33 AM,01/01/2020 07:43 AM 
charge11004,cust202272,17,405,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:43 AM 
charge11008,cust202397,28,446,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:42 AM 
charge11016,cust202071,36,421,01/01/2020 06:33 AM,01/01/2020 07:42 AM 
charge11028,cust202454,38,441,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:41 AM 
charge11030,cust202489,00,440,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:42 AM 
charge11015,cust202305,29,416,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:42 AM 
charge11013,cust202044,02,437,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:42 AM 
charge11017,cust202451,38,425,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:43 AM 
charge11020,cust202217,15,449,01/01/2020 06:34 AM,01/01/2020 07:42 AM 
charge11014,cust202391,03,417,01/01/2020 06:33 AM,01/01/2020 07:44 AM
```

This is what I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd

locations = pd.read_csv("evc_locations.csv")
logs = pd.read_csv("evc_logs.csv")
location_logs = pd.merge(locations, logs, 
                   on='charger_id', 
                   how='inner')
location_logs[['start_time','end_time']]=location_logs[['start_time','end_time']].apply(pd.to_datetime,1)

output = location_logs.groupby('location_id').apply(lambda x : (x['start_time']-x['end_time'].shift()).dt.total_seconds().mean()/60)
print(output)
```

This is what I get:

```
location_id
loc1001     NaN
loc1002     NaN
loc1003     NaN
loc1004     NaN
loc1005   -69.0
loc1006   -69.5
loc1007     NaN
loc1008   -69.0
loc1010   -70.5
loc1011   -71.0
oc1001      NaN
```

Comment: When you `groupby('location_id')`, you are dividing the DataFrame into smallers frame, each with the same `location_id`. Some frames have only 1 row. That's why you get so many `NaN`.

Comment: I also don't understand what this is supposed to do: `x['start_time']-x['end_time'].shift()`. Are you trying to find the idle time of each charger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
func = lambda grp: (grp['end_time'] - grp['start_time']).mean().seconds/3600
location_logs.groupby('location_id').apply(func)
```

Outputs:

```
location_id
loc1001    1.166667
loc1002    1.150000
loc1003    1.150000
loc1004    1.133333
loc1005    1.144444
loc1006    1.150000
loc1007    1.150000
loc1008    1.141667
loc1010    1.166667
loc1011    1.175000
oc1001     1.166667
dtype: float64
```